# Vue router object is null

Tags: javascript, browserify, vue.js

I've got a problem with vue.

My login looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {router} from '../main';

export default {

  user: {
    authenticated: false,
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    email: ''
  },

  login (context, creds) {
    Vue.http.post('/api/login', creds)
      .then(({data: {token}}) => {
        // Hide the error message in case this time
        // the creds were valid.
        context.hideError();

        this.setToken(token);
        this.getUserInfo(token);

        router.go({ path: '/home' });
      }, (error) => {
        // Show some error message on the invoking vm
        // telling the user that his/her credentials
        // are wrong.
        context.showError();
      });
  },

.....
```

But for some reason my `router object` is `null`. I receive the error: `Cannot read property 'go' of undefined(…)`

I'm importing the router from main.js

Where I make the router like this:

```
var router = new Router({
    history: true
});
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here!

Comment: You need to export your router in main.js !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Thanks that works :)

Comment: Please add an answer and mark it as accepted (so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily).

Answer (score 2):

I had this:

```
var router = new Router({
  history: true
});
```

Instead of this:

```
export var router = new Router({
  history: true
});
```

@Ismail RBOUH Thanks for helping.